# RxJS: Что такое наблюдаемая последовательность?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, реактивное-программирование

Не совсем понимаю как и для чего используют библиотеку `RxJS`. А именно, понимаю что такое `subscribe`, но при попытки использовать другие "навороты" библиотеки уже засомнивался и в этом.
Вот к примеру, до сих пор использование этой библиотеки мною ограничивалось следующим:

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 
...   
    users: User[]=[];

    constructor(private userService: UserService){}

    ngOnInit(){

        this.httpService.getUsers().subscribe(data => this.users=data);
    }
}
```

**user.service.ts**

```
    @Injectable()
    export class HttpService {

        constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
        }

    getUsers() : Observable<User[]> {
        return this.http.get('/api/users').map(data => {
            let usersList = data["usersList"];
            return usersList.map(function(user:any) {
                return {name: user.userName, age: user.userAge};
              });
        });
    }
}
```

И вот как все понимаю я: *Если не правильно прокоментирую код, то подправьте*

- происходит инициализации компонента `AppComponent`;
- в этот момент вызывается метод `getUsers()` у сервиса `UserService` и
  тут же компонент `AppComponent` подписывается на результат вызова
  `UserService.getUsers`;
- вызов `UserService.getUsers` происходит в отдельном потоке, это значит
  что `AppComponent` на этом не останавливается и идет дальше;
- под подпиской на результат вызова `UserService.getUsers` компонентом
  `AppComponent` я понимаю - после вызова ты указываешь функцию с одним
  параметром, которой надо в качестве параметра передать результат вызова
  `UserService.getUsers`.

---

Теперь я хочу в деталях понять этот код:

```
var button = document.querySelector('button');
var source = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click');
source.subscribe(x => {
  console.log('Next: Clicked!');
});
```

В самом начале [описании](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromevent.md) метода `fromEvent` есть строчка:

> Creates an observable sequence by adding an event listener to ...

Мне кажется, что мое не понимание начинается с того что тут говорится о том что создается некая **наблюдаемая последовательность**.
Я это понимаю как своего рода какой-то контейнер куда скапливаются все клики и они по очередности обрабатываются той функцией которую мы укажем.

Все ли правильно я понимаю?

Answer (score -1):

Немного странный у вас код, в AppComponent ngOnInit используется httpService, хотя в конструктор вы передаете (и показываете) userService: UserService

- происходит инициализации компонента AppComponent
- в этот момент вызывается метод getUsers() у сервиса UserService и тут же компонент AppComponent подписывается на результат вызова UserService.getUsers;

Метод getUsers() у сервиса UserService возвращает "наблюдаемый объект" Observable -- и теперь мы хотим его наблюдать, у него подписываясь методом subscribe

- вызов UserService.getUsers происходит в отдельном потоке, это значит что AppComponent на этом не останавливается и идет дальше;

Нет, вызов UserService.getUsers уже произошел в прошлом пункте и вернул нам "наблюдаемый объект" Observable. Мы просто подписались на него (можно сказать, передали ему коллбэк) и кода незамедлительно исполняется дальше. Больше нас объект Observable не интересует, т.к. данные мы получим в колбэке, которые мы передали в subscribe

- под подпиской на результат вызова UserService.getUsers компонентом AppComponent я понимаю - после вызова ты указываешь функцию с одним параметром, которой надо в качестве параметра передать результат вызова UserService.getUsers.

Нет, в подписку нужно передать функцию, принимающую User[], т.к. наш "наблюдаемый объект" Observable оборачивает нужные нам данные User[].

...

Все ли правильно я понимаю?

Да, создается "наблюдаемый объект" из событий кликов, на которого можно подписываться, и каждый раз при клике будет вызываться коллбэк

Comment: нет такого понятия как "наблюдаемый объект". rxjs всего лишь имплементирует nodejs stream api, а observable это абстракция поверх обычных потоков. к тому же "передача коллбэка", как вы выразились, не значит подписаться, есть холодные и горячие потоки, есть потоки которые генерируют данные асинхронно, вне зависимости от того, подписан на них кто-то или нет